# Calling python script failing with import error when called from shell script (.prog) used in Oracle host programs

Tags: shell, unix, python-2.6

I am trying to call a python script.method from a host (.prog) shell script.

Both `.prog` & `XX_PACKET_GEN.py` files are in `XX_TOP/bin` directory.

```
#!/bin/ksh
python -c "import XX_PACKET_GEN; XX_PACKET_GEN.main('$l_dir','$l_file_name')"

Error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named XX_PACKET_GEN
```

I tried `sys.append(absolute path of XX_TOP/bin)`, but no luck

The same script works if I try `$ sh test.sh` (test file makes same call to python script) but fails from `.prog` file.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sys.path.append`? Alternatively, explicitly set the environment variable PYTHONPATH  before invoking Python.

Comment: Hi, I got it to work. At the time of calling python script, my current directory is diff from directory where the python script is. About sys.path.. yes I used the same.